# Programatically compile generated .cpp file with c#?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, compilation

I generated a .cpp file programmatically with c# and save it as a.cpp in "D:\" .
My problem is how to compile this file programmatically in C# using anything like visual studio?

Comment: You call the msvc c++ compiler to compile it?

Comment: Provided that you have VS installed, just use the cl.exe to compile your file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw.aspx

Comment: @AndrejBratoz How to use this .exe file?

Comment: cl.exe is the MS C++ compiler. Refer to the link about it's usage. Start a new process in C#, pass the arguments and voilà!

Comment: _@Mohammad_ _"How ?"_ Like @AndrejBratoz said.

Comment: @AndrejBratoz could you please give me a piece of code?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ could you please give me a piece of code ? I totally confused

Comment: @Mohammad There's plenty of code examples how to start another process from C#, the parameters needed for the cl.exe compiler are well described in the link you were given. So what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have VS installer, you can compile you C++ files using cl.exe, which is the MS C++ compiler.

To do that from C#, you need to start a process:

```
var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cl.exe" // bear in mind you actually need the full path
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "..." // that would be your cpp file and probably some switches
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit(); // call only if you would like that the program execution waits untill that process finishes
```

Comment: my .cpp file is in D:\\a.cpp . what should I pass to proc as arguments.

Comment: Please give me a brief answer.

Comment: well for starters `D:\\a.cpp`

Comment: Does not work. Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Well unfortunately my help can be very limited from here since I do not have much to work with. Debugging is the way to go.